# C++: Filescope constants with same name are breaking one definition rule?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have 2 constants in 2 different `.cpp` files, 
 both named `const char const * TEXTURE_FILENAME = "...";`

One is in `a.cpp` and the other is in `b.cpp`, at the file scope, and neither file includes the other or should see one another, but VS2010 generates this linker error:

`a.obj : error LNK2005: "char const * const TEXTURE_FILENAME" (?TEXTURE_FILENAME@@3PBDB) already defined in b.obj`

What am I doing wrong here, and how might I fix it without needing to rename either constant?

Comment: These are not constants, they're pointers to constants.

Comment: @immibis - thanks for pointing that out, I fixed them so they are constant pointers, but the same linker error happens I'm afraid

Comment: How did you fix them?

Comment: @immibis - incorrectly apparently!  I did `const char const *` when I should've used `const char * const` which DID fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here, and how might I fix it without needing to rename either constant?

You are defining two objects named `TEXTURE_FILENAME`. That's the problem.

There are more than one ways to fix the problem.  The simplest fix is to make them `static` in file scope.

```
static const char * TEXTURE_FILENAME = "...";
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

`TEXTURE_FILENAME` is not a `const` object. It happens to point to a C style string that is `const`. You can modify where `TEXTURE_FILENAME` elsewhere in the file by using:

```
TEXTURE_FILENAME = <some other C style string>;
```

To make `TEXTURE_FILENAME` a `const`, you'll need to use:

```
// Both the pointer and what it points to are const.
const char * const TEXTURE_FILENAME = "...";
```

Comment: Aren't `const` objects `static` by default?

Comment: @immibis - `TEXTURE_OBJECT` as defined in the question is not a `const` object. It's a modifiable pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker "@immibis - thanks for pointing that out, I fixed them so they are constant pointers, but the same linker error happens I'm afraid"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have two copies of that pointer in the two files, or one copy that is used by both?

If you want two copies, one in each file, just mark them `static`; that will make each one visible only in the file in which it's defined.

If you want a single copy, visible to both files, change **one** of the files to read

```
extern const char * TEXTURE_FILENAME;
```

I'm confused by the inconsistent uses of `const` in the question, so adjust that however is appropriate. The point being that by removing the initializer and adding `extern` you tell the compiler that `TEXTURE_FILENAME` is defined in a some other file.